# SimpleDateFormat for this RFC-like timestamp?

Tags: java, scala, simpledateformat

Trying to parse the following timestamp:

`2008-09-19T19:05:30.000Z`

However I am getting a parseException. Is anyone aware of a class or SimpleDateFormat that could take care of this?

What I am using now in Scala (Java answers work, too):

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.Z")`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And single quotes (`'`) around the `Z`. This instructs the parser to treat `Z` as a constant character (just like the `T`). Also add in `SSS` for the milliseconds. Thus your pattern would be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

Comment: I can confirm this also worked, and switching it to the answer on the reason that it accounts for ms

Comment: @DeLongey (Which you can't get in a trivial way from a `Date`.) If you must match the pattern *exactly*, you must *also* `setLenient(false)` or it will match inexact patterns.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code from Google client libraries did the trick:

http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.0.10-alpha/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime.html

Use the parseRFC3339 method.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Z`:

```
> sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
> println sdf.parse("2008-09-19T19:05:30.000Z")
Fri Sep 19 19:05:30 EDT 2008
```

Comment: This is a suboptimal answer in that it relies on SimpleDateFormat not matching anything after the format string. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428313/simpledateformat-parsestring-str-didnt-been-throw-when-str-2011-12-12aaaaaa

Comment: @SteveKuo Agreed, if OP actually *needs* the ms... which is a pain with a `Date` anyway. Of course, you'd also need to `setLenient(false)`, otherwise non-exact patterns may still match.