# Using ~ in SimpleDateFormat#parse()

Tags: java, sql, simpledateformat, date-parsing

The below code is executing without any problems. But logically it seems to be incorrect. Why is it so?

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

DateFormat df =new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

new Date(df.parse("09/01/3~34").getTime());   // Produces '09/01/3'
new Date(df.parse("09/01/100000").getTime()); // Produces ' 000-09-01'
```

Comment: 1. The parser stops after reading something which it can interpret. 2. The parser can be *lenient*.

Comment: What is the value of `parsedDate`? I guess `3-01-09`.

Comment: yes I got `0003-09-01` .   this I am getting even for `df.parse("09/01/3~qwwww")`

Comment: It doesn't appear to be because it's `lenient`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat parse(string str) didn't been throw when str = 2011/12/12aaaaaaaaa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428313/simpledateformat-parsestring-str-didnt-been-throw-when-str-2011-12-12aaaaaa)

Comment: so we can never parse date that falls in 100 th century in java using MM/dd/yyyy format?

Comment: Course we can. Try to parse `09/01/45` and you'll see that the year `45` is parsed accordingly even using the `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: Please stop editing your question changing the original content

Comment: Did I solved your questions?

Comment: yes ofcourse your answer solved my first query..

Comment: But the second question is still open.I dont understand why this bug is missed in JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First question:**

```
new Date(df.parse("09/01/3~34").getTime());   // Produces '09/01/3'
```

According to [DateFormat#parse() JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29):

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. **The method may not use the entire text of the given string**.

Because of that, after it parses the value from the String, it stops searching on it. When it found the `~` sign, it parsed the `3` value to the year and stopped looking on the String.

**Second question:**

```
new Date(df.parse("09/01/100000").getTime()); // Produces ' 000-09-01'
```

It's not producing '000-09-01'. The following code:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
java.util.Date parsedDate = df.parse("09/01/100000");

System.out.println(parsedDate);
System.out.println(df.format(parsedDate));
```

Outputs:

```
Fri Sep 01 00:00:00 BRT 100000
09/01/100000
```

However, it appears to be a bug with the `java.sql.Date#toString` method on JDK. To present this `java.sql.Date` correctly, try passing it to your `DateFormat#format` method:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDt = new java.sql.Date(df.parse("09/01/10000").getTime());
System.out.println(df.format(sqlDt));
```

**Output:** `09/01/100000`

Comment: in that case why `Date parsedDate = new Date(df.parse("09/01/100000").getTime());` is returning `000-09-01`

Comment: I didnt use java.util.date ..I am using java.sql.date. Can you please check how sql.date is behaving with `09/01/100000 `

Comment: It appears to be a bug with the `java.sql.Date#toString` method. Apparently, it doesn't understand correctly years over `9999`. To present this date correctly, try using the same DateFormat: `df.format(parsedDt)`.

Answer (score 0):

**About first question:**

The class `SimpleDateFormat` is VERY lenient and just stops when some invalid chars are hit. Even when you explicitly instruct it to parse strict via `df.setLenient(false);` you will notice here the same output and no exception. JodaTime, JSR-310 or my time library would correctly reject the input containing invalid chars in strict mode. So here we have a clear bug in JDK.

**About second question:**

Well, you use `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`. The sql-version is not designed for years > 9999. This is even specified in its javadoc:

"date milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT not to exceed the milliseconds representation for the year 8099"

Not quite clear in javadoc but Oracle speaks about year offset of 1900 so finally `java.sql.Date` only supports the year range up to 9999. This is conform with ANSI-SQL, so no that year limitation itself is not a bug, but necessary for interoperability with SQL. Instead another aspect is bad and in my opinion a bug, namely: If you feed the constructor with an invalid year then you don`t get any exception but internally the state will be silently set to something silly and unpredictable.

**Conclusion:**

Avoid to use `java.sql.Date` for anything else than in JDBC layer. It is not for the application layer. Furthermore, `java.util.Date` and also `SimpleDateFormat` (which are the "standard" in Java-pre8) are more or less horribly broken. Good alternatives are JodaTime, in Java 8 the new JSR-310-API or my library if it reaches non-alpha-state one day.