# Check if a string contains only date

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have a string which can contain a date(yyyy-MM-dd) or date and time (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) in respective formats.

I want to know which strings contains only date.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(dateFormat.parse("2015-02-02"));
System.out.println(dateFormat.parse("2015-02-02 23:23:23"));
```

In above code, both the strings are parsed successfully, whereas the format is same for only first.

Comment: use regular expression.

Comment: For that particular pattern, you could just check that the length of the input is 10. For variable-length patterns, it's slightly harder - there are alternative parse methods which allow you to see how much of the string has been parsed. (See `parse(String, ParsePosition)`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I also thought of that solution, but it seems more like an alternative.

Comment: @Jon, slighly better IMO is checking if  the string contains a ':',  ( in case a valid time somewhere strange is 10 long) but both are likely fine.

Comment: @SahilJain does regex help you

Comment: @ankur-singhal: Why use a regex when you're already parsing?

Comment: Thinking more about this question, I really want to know this: **WHY?**  Could you elaborate on the requirement?  If all you need is the date, why do you care if the String also contains a time, my pet's name, whatever afterwards, so long as you can parse a date?  If this input is coming from a file, your XML parser or tokenizer should care, but that should be done **well before** you pass the token  to the Date parser.

Comment: @user949300 I am pointing to different database columns based on the incoming string.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the overload of `parse` which takes a `ParsePosition` - you can then check the position afterwards:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        System.out.println(parseFully(dateFormat, "2015-02-02"));
        System.out.println(parseFully(dateFormat, "2015-02-02 23:23:23"));
    }

    private static Date parseFully(DateFormat format, String text) 
          throws ParseException {
        ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
        Date date = format.parse(text, position);
        if (position.getIndex() == text.length()) {
            return date;
        }
        if (date == null) {
            throw new ParseException("Date could not be parsed: " + text,
                                     position.getErrorIndex());
        }
        throw new ParseException("Date was parsed incompletely: " + text,
                                 position.getIndex());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jon for the idea. I think that comparing pattern length and date string length is the best possible solution so far.

Comment: @SahilJain: That's fine *if* it's a fixed-length pattern. If you've got a pattern like `"EEE dd MMM yyyy"` then it won't work.

Comment: I might quibble that this fails (I think???) for an input with a space at the end, which may be common, and you may wish to consider "legal".  If so, be sure to call `trim()` first.

Comment: @user949300: I would *want* it to fail in that case, personally - it's not "just a date" at that point. But yes, you can always trim it...

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateOnly = "2015-02-02";
        String dateAndTimeOnly = "2015-02-02 23:23:23";
        System.out.println("Date Only = " + validateDateFormat(dateOnly));
        System.out.println("Date And time Only = " + validateDateFormat(dateAndTimeOnly));
    }

    public static boolean validateDateFormat(String input) {

        return input.matches("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})");
    }
```

**output**

```
Date Only = true
Date And time Only = false
```

Regex is self explanatory - Input will be separated by `-`, ist part(`[0-9]{4}`) can contain 4 digit , 2nd part can contain 2 digit `[0-9]{2}`, so as 3rd.

Comment: Seems like overkill when checking length 10 or for presence of. ':' also work.  What would this regex catch where those fail?

Comment: @user949300 eg for input

Comment: O.k., yes, in general case, or if user we're typing, you'd want a regex.  However, OP specified that the Strings are already highly limited and structured.

Comment: @user949300 i agree with your points, reading OP question, his solution did not work, why it did not worked explained by `San Krish`, he also wanted to have alternate solutions, which can be many considering your input and considering OP input is very well structured.

Comment: Also this allows invalid dates. If you're not really going to validate that it's a date, why not just check the length?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes agree, as per OP, just wanted to differentiate between two dates format with regex. Yes Regex can be further modified..

Comment: But I don't see why a regex is a good idea at all? It's more complicated than a length check, and less rigorous than using a different overload of `DateFormat.parse` (as per my answer). Where is the benefit in using it?

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

Let's first try to do it the way you have done:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "2015-02-02", "2015-02-02 23:23:23" };
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println("Attempting to parse '" + s + "':");
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(s, dtf);
            System.out.println("Parsed successfully: " + date);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Attempting to parse '2015-02-02':
> Parsed successfully: 2015-02-02
> Attempting to parse '2015-02-02 23:23:23':
> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text
>  '2015-02-02 23:23:23' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10

As you can see, the `java.time` API correctly throws an exception informing you about the problem. `SimpleDateFormat`, on the other hand, parses the input string silently which has caused the problem that you have posted.

Thus, with the modern date-time API, you have two easy options:

1. Simply catch the exception and say that the second input (i.e. `2015-02-02 23:23:23`) is not a date string as per the specified date pattern.
2. Use the function, [`DateTimeFormatter#parse(CharSequence, ParsePosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.text.ParsePosition-) with the `ParsePosition` index set to `0`.

Given below is a demo of the second option:

```
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "2015-02-02", "2015-02-02 23:23:23" };
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

        for (String s : arr) {
            ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
            LocalDate.from(dtf.parse(s, pp));
            if (pp.getIndex() < s.length()) {
                System.out.println("'" + s + "' is not a date string as per the specified date pattern.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> '2015-02-02 23:23:23' is not a date string as per the specified date pattern.

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Rr2WA2)

**Note:** [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Once the desired `format` is reached , `SimpleDateFormat` doesnt format the rest of `String` . It is the reason why your second string is parsed.

This post [SimpleDateFormat parse(string str) doesn't throw an exception when str = 2011/12/12aaaaaaaaa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428313/simpledateformat-parsestring-str-didnt-been-throw-when-str-2011-12-12aaaaaa) may help you .

Also check the [`DateFormat#parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) method in java docs

Comment: Yes, i am understanding what java is doing there. But i am looking for a good solution for my problem and also want to understand why does java does not check for whole string. I tried to set lenient to false also, still not able to find the desired output

Comment: Have you read the answers in the post linked , it will make you clear . comment if you dont understand :)